# Stuck at date-format in seconds

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5

first of all, I'm sorry for my english. I'm from germany.

Now my Problem:
I have a multiple array with some dates in it. I had to filter the first and the last date for every IP because I need the difference of both dates to know how much time the User on my website. 
I did that and got all I need. Here is a part of my code output:

$ip_with_dates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 72.xx.xx.xx
            [first_date] => 2015-10-12 00:10:15
            [last_date] => 2015-10-12 01:10:51
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 85.xx.xx.xx
            [first_date] => 2015-10-12 00:10:19
            [last_date] => 2015-10-12 01:10:56
        )
```

I tried to get the time between those two dates with:

```
    $visit_lenght = [];
    foreach($ip_with_date as $key => $val){
        $date1 = new DateTime($val['first_date']);
        $date2 = new DateTime($val['last_date']);
        $interval = $date1->diff($date2)->format('%h %m %s');
        $visit_lenght[] = $interval;
    }
```

what gives me this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 36
    [1] => 1 37
    [2] => 0 3
    [3] => 0 9
)
```

well but this isn't good to work with. I need the time in seconds not in H:m:s

but I really don't now how. This is a part of my project where I'm really fighting with. Maybe someone of you could help me with this.

I'm working with laravel. Normal PHP would make it too but if someone knows a solution in laravel, it would be nice as well!

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get time diff in seconds you need to convert your datetime objects to timestamps:

```
$visit_lenght = [];
foreach($ip_with_date as $key => $val){
    $date1 = new DateTime($val['first_date']);
    $date2 = new DateTime($val['last_date']);
    $interval = $date1->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp()
    $visit_lenght[] = $interval;
}
```

Comment: well I tried this but the output is a little bit strange..  ----

    [0] => 3636
    [1] => 3637
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 9
)

Comment: Mark answer as accepted, so everyone can see that it is right :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may get timestamps of two dates and count the difference.
something like (in php).

```
$date1t = $date1->getTimestamp();
$date2t = $date2->getTimestamp();
$diff = $date2t - $date1t;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (general/basic way)

```
$visit_lenght = [];
    foreach($ip_with_date as $key => $val){
        $date1 = strtotime($val['first_date']);
        $date2 = strtotime($val['last_date']);
        //$interval = $date1->diff($date2)->format('%h %m %s');
$interval = $date2 - $date1;
        $visit_lenght[] = $interval;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make this:
->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Answer (score 0):

With `DateTime()` class of PHP, it is super simple to find difference between time. Here is an exmple:

```
<?php
    $ip = "xxxx-xxx-xxx";
    $t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-12 00:10:15');
    $t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-12 01:10:51');

    echo "User from IP {$ip} spent " . $t1->diff($t2)->format("%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds");
?>
```